# R: How to group data by numerical ranges and visualize it grouped by a category and these ranges?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, group, gplots

I have data like this:

| DL | Rel | SL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | amod | 12 |
| 1 | amod | 12 |
| 2 | det | 12 |
| 1 | amod | 12 |
| 4 | nmod | 12 |
| 2 | det | 12 |
| 1 | amod | 12 |
| 4 | appos | 12 |
| 1 | case | 9 |
| 2 | case | 9 |
| 1 | amod | 9 |
| 4 | nmod | 9 |
| 1 | appos | 9 |
| 1 | case | 44 |
| 2 | nmod | 44 |
| 1 | cop | 44 |
| 6 | mark | 44 |
| 1 | det | 44 |
| 4 | nsubj | 44 |

I want to make ranges of the SL-column like (0-10), (11-20), (21-30), (31+) and then group the Rel-column according to the ranges. The result should be something like:

[image]

The code I have so far is:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(r02pro)
f_rel <- read.csv(file = '....csv' , sep = ',')
g1 <- ggplot(data = f_rel, aes(x = SL, y = DL)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
g1 + facet_wrap("Rel")
```

What I get is:

[image]

So I can not manage to get the ranges. Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: consider using `cut_interval(SL, length = 10)`

Comment: Add a binned version of `DL` as per Onyambu's code or the marked duplicate, then make your combined column `paste`ing together your binned DL column and `Rel`.